# How to load a Java applet class from a subfolder with the embed tag?

Tags: java, html, applet, embed

I have a Java Applet as a single class file (No JAR file) in some sub directory and I want to embed it on a HTML page which is in a different directory. And I want to use the `embed` tag for it. But I can't get it working. This is my code so far:

```
<embed type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
       width="512" height="512"
       code="subfolder/MyApplet.class" />
```

According to the Apache log file the Class file is loaded but it can't be started. Java says there is no class with name `subfolder.MyApplet`. So it treats the sub directory as a package name. A `codebase` parameter (No idea if this is valid for `embed`) doesn't make a difference. Maybe there is some other badly documented parameter to specifiy a code base directory from which to load the classes?

Please note that my question is not about how to embed a Java applet in general. I know how to get it running with the deprecated `applet` tag or the `object` tag and by packaging the class into a JAR file. My question is how to get it working in exactly this specific situation:

- No JAR file, only single class file.
- Class file is not in the same directory as the HTML page.
- Using `embed` tag.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I'm evaluating the various ways to embed a Java applet. The HTML 5 spec says that this tag is to be used for Java applets instead of the deprecated `applet` tag. So why do you think `embed` is invalid? Evaluating this complex deployment script from Oracle/Sun is on my TODO list but to be honest I prefer using a few lines of standard HTML code instead of including a large library from Oracle with lots of compressed magic functions in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the 'codebase' tag when using the 'embed' tag. For example,

```
   <embed type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
       width="512" height="512"
       code="MyApplet.class" 
       codebase="subfolder/"/>
```

You should be able to use relative and absolute paths in the 'codebase' tag.

Hope that helps...

Comment: revised to change `java_codebase` tag to `codebase` tag. `java_codebase` is in use with the `<object>` tag.

Comment: Hm... I tried `codebase` before and it wasn't working. But after changing the class name it now magically works. Looks like I had some caching problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
<embed type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
       width="512" height="512"
       codebase="subfolder/"
       code="MyApplet.class" />
```

Refer to [this documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/using_tags.html).

Comment: Thanks. See my comment in the other answer. Can't see which one of you answered first so I accepted the answer with the lower reputation. I hope you don't mind :-)